# get json data object with coffeescript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript

In coffeescript, I'm using this to load a json file

```
  $.ajax 'json/data.json',
        success  : (res, status, xhr, data) ->
            console.log("yea "+data)
        error    : (xhr, status, err) ->
            console.log("nah "+err)
        complete : (xhr, status) ->
            console.log("comp")
```

file loads but data comes up is undefined?

Comment: are you sure server is sending back any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success takes different set of arguments:

```
success
Type: Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

Try this:

```
$.ajax 'json/data.json',
        success  : (data, status, xhr) ->
            console.log("yea "+data)
        error    : (xhr, status, err) ->
            console.log("nah "+err)
        complete : (xhr, status) ->
            console.log("comp")
```